# How to catch group In regex which includes newLine?

Tags: c#, regex

I have that kind of paragraph  ,  and i need to catch into group the INSIDE CONTENT !

e.g. : I need to cathe **ANYTHING** between **AAA** and **BBB** ( AAA,BBB should **not** be included ) , please notice new lines  ,  \t \r \n between AAA and BBB

```
 AAA
          I Love You  /// can be any charcter + specials !!

    BBB
```

expected output : 
 matches[0].Groups[1].ToString() ===>  I Love You

Comment: is AAA and BBB must be in this order or can be "BBB"..."BBB" or "AAA"..."AAA" or "BBB"..."AAA" as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following pattern:

```
@"AAA([\s\S]+)BBB"
```

Comment: how the \S doesn't include the BBB ? the '+' suppose to be greedy ...?

Comment: `\s` matches whitespace characters, `\S` matches non-whitespace characters. Combining the two is just a way of saying capture *everything*.

Comment: That pattern is greedy (it will swallow all but the last BBB). Just change `+` to `+?` if you need a non-greedy match.

Comment: theres a problem - the group will also contains the \r charcter. so it gives me **I Love You\r** insteaed of** I Love You**

Comment: You did say you wanted to capture "**ANYTHING** between **AAA** and **BBB**". Change the pattern to `AAA\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*BBB` if you want to strip out leading and trailing white space.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that the two string are there in that order and apear only once (you can check this), you can use the [String.split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method.

```
    String[] seperators={"AAA","BBB"};
    String[] contents=paragraph.split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.None);
    String content=contents[1]; //the content between the two seperator strings
```

good luck!